# for loop and variables

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file

How can I define the number of loops as variable to change it out side of the loop instead of the number 10 here in my example?

I meant is it possible to write like this

```
: @echo off

set Looping_number=10 or anything else

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,Looping_number) DO call :doit %%A
goto :eof

:doit
set pad=00%1
set num=%pad:~-2%
@set var1=var1.exe
@set var2=C:\...\...\... .txt
@set output=C:\....\output\%num%
Mkdir %output%
%var1%     %var2%     %Results%   
goto :eof
```

this one doesn't work with me?
any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `%` signs around the variable when you refer to it:

```
set Looping_number=10 or anything else

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%Looping_number%) DO call :doit %%A
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer